# Facebook App URL showing domain

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

How is it possible to make my (ASP.NET MVC3) application written for Facebook use (show) URLs like in [this](http://apps.facebook.com/sweepstakeshq/) application?

Notice that if you hoover over a link on that facebook application the URL changes to http://apps.facebook.com/namespace-of-that-application.

In my application instead i get  http://MY-DOMAIN.COM/SOME-LINK. Obviously i 'm doing somthing wrong! What?

Comment: Silly question: your app does in fact have a canvas ('App on Facebook') implementation accessible at apps.facebook.com/something, right?

Comment: @Igy ..well: if you ask if the canvas URL has been set then the answer is yes! If your question focuses on something else, the answer is: i don't know! (it 's my first app for FB)

Comment: If your app has a canvas URL, links to that app should go to the canvas URL first

Comment: I understand that by setting a canvas URL the application is pulled from there, but shouldn't (somehow) the domain name be replaced by http://app.facebook.com/ followed by all the rest

Comment: No, i'm saying that if your app is a canvas app, the 'posted X minutes ago via AppName' links at the bottom of posts made by your app should be going to that canvas app - if this isn't happening, you may not have the canvas settings correctly entered for your app

Comment: Amongst others i have set: Canvas Page, Canvas URL, Page Tab Name, Page Tab URL. Am i missing something?